# javascript parse nested json with dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, hash, nested

I'm trying to parse some nested json returned by an api call. Below is a simplified version of what is being returned.

```
{
  "Includes":{
    "Products":{
      "P123456":{
        "Brand":{},
        "Description":"ipsem lorem",
        "Statistics":
          [
           "Author":"John Smith",
           "IsFeatured":false,
           "Total": 3
          ]
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

I've tried several different syntaxes to get what I need where product_code = "P123456"

```
data.Includes.Products.product_code.Statistics
data.Includes.Products[product_code].Statistics
```

I've also tried using 'get' and 'eval' to no avail. The error response is always the same

```
application.js:1639 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Statistics' of undefined
```

I know the product code is correct as I have console logged it. I have also successfully console.logged

```
data.Includes.Products["P123456"].Statistics
```

How can I access the data nested under the product code, "P123456" ? The project uses zepto and not jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.keys(data.Includes.Products)` will return an array of keys under products.

If you want the first one `Object.keys(data.Includes.Products)[0]`.

Statistics can be retrieved

```
var key = Object.keys(data.Includes.Products);
var statistics = data.Includes.Products[key].Statistics;
```

Pure JavaScript ... no libraries.

PS. Your JSON is malformed. That "Statistics" array is going to cause tears.

Comment: This worked, thank you. None of the other answers seemed to take note that I have no control over the data being returned. I tried using $.getJSON and $.ajax. I'm unexperienced with js and json, would you mind explaining how the json is malformed? Not sure why my question was downvoted.

Comment: Glad I could help. Your "Statistics" key points to an Array [ ] should be another object { }. @Nina Scholz has the correct JSON in her answer. Not sure about the downvotes :(

Comment: BTW. Can you tag this as the correct answer. I'm new and need the rep so I can comment outside of my answers.

Answer (score 1):

With valid data structure, you can access it via

```
object.Includes.Products.P123456
```

or

```
object.Includes.Products[product_code]
```

```js
var object = {
        "Includes": {
            "Products": {
                "P123456": {
                    "Brand": {},
                    "Description": "ipsem lorem",
                    "Statistics": { // its an object, not an array
                        "Author": "John Smith",
                        "IsFeatured": false,
                        "Total": 3
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    product_code = 'P123456';

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object.Includes.Products.P123456, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object.Includes.Products[product_code], 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried this? `data.Includes.Products.P123456.Statistics` ? It looks like property and not a indexed string.